# Calculate OLS estimators by differentiating an equation

Tags: r

I need to calculate the OLS estimators by differencing the equation. 
However, I am not able to translate the equation in R.
I am using the `lm()` function to model the equation.

[image: Youll find the equation in the image]

[image: The correct OLS which I need to obtain]

The R-code:

```
library(data.table)
library(sandwich) 
library(lmtest) 
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plm)
library(margins)
con <- SQLite() %>% dbConnect('wooldridge.db')
rental <- con %>% dbReadTable('rentak') %>% data.table
rental <- con %>% dbReadTable('rental') %>% data.table

#The translated equation written by me which supposedly is giving the wrong answers upon running summary 

fit <- lm(diff(lrent)~diff(lpop)+diff(lavginc)+diff(pctstu),data=rental) %>% 
summary(fit)
```

I would appreciate some clarification regarding the same.

Comment: Why don't you run the model first with `lm()` and then use `summary()` to get the coefficients? Try something like `fit <- lm(lrent ~ lpop + lavginc + pctstu, data=rental)` and then `summary(fit)`. You will get the coefficient for each explanatory variable

Comment: This is not a [MCVE] yet, but maybe you can make it one and prevent it being closed. Is this at all related to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wooldridge/index.html